# Equation for the equipotential lines?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dipole

What is the equation for the equipotential lines in $x$-$y$ plane for a dipole oriented along the $x$ axis?

Comment: Write down the potential for both positive and negative charge, and equate it to a constant. i.e. $V_+(x,y) + V_-(x,y) = c$

Comment: I tried but it didnt match.. The answer is  x/((x^2+y^2)^(3/2)) = Constant

Comment: Sounds like you have a math problem then

Comment: @DavidH Your prescription gives the equipotentials of a dipole consisting of two oppositely charged particles placed a certain distance away; I think the question is referring to a pure dipole; see the response below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In three dimensions, the electric potential $V$ of a [*pure* dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Field_from_an_electric_dipole) $\mathbf p$ located at the origin is given by
\begin{align}
  V(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf x}{|\mathbf x|^3}
\end{align}
If the dipole is oriented along the $x$-axis, then we have $\mathbf p = p\hat{\mathbf x}$ which gives $\mathbf p \cdot\mathbf x = px$.  Moreover, notice that
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{|\mathbf x|^3} = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3} = \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}
Putting this all together gives the following expression for the potential:
\begin{align}
  V(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{px}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}
\end{align}
As pointed out in the comments, the equation for an equipotential is then obtained by setting this expression to a constant.  This gives
\begin{align}
  \frac{x}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3} = \mathrm{const.}
\end{align}
If one is interested only in the equation for equipotentials in the $x$-$y$ plane, one can set $z=0$ which gives precisely your quoted result.

Comment: Is this potential for the case when $|\bf{x}| \gg |\bf{p}|$?

Comment: @H.R. The pure dipole potential applies for all $\mathbf x \neq 0$, not just positions with large norms.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to say that! Just consider two opposite charges on the $x$ axis located at $x=-1$ and $x=+1$. The potential on the $x$ axis will be $V=\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{2}{x^2-1}$ which doesn't equal with your formula here! For sure, there is an approximation!

Comment: @H.R. No.  A pure dipole is defined as the limit in which the charges become infinitely close while keeping the dipole moment fixed (by requiring the charges to increase appropriately).  In this limit, one finds the expression I wrote.  Try doing the computation for charges $\pm q/\epsilon$ with positions $\pm \epsilon a \hat{\mathbf z}$.  Expand the potential to first non-vanishing order in $\epsilon$, use the definition of dipole moment, and everything will work out.

Comment: So there is an approximation just inside the definition of the pure dipole which I was not aware of! :) Thanks. :)

Comment: @H.R. Sure if you insist, but I'd prefer to call it an idealization rather than an approximation since one can rigorously take the limit I mention and get that precise expression -- no approximations actually necessary :)

Comment: Yes, maybe idealization is a better word! :) Anyway, for the final question, is there any such formula for dipoles with the same or opposite charges (no idealization included)? I think the answer should be *NO*.

Comment: @H.R. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  What does it mean for a dipole to have a charge?

Comment: I mean two charges $+q,+q$ or $+q,-q$. Sorry for bad terminology but I have seen it on Wiki.

Comment: @H.R. The dipole formula I wrote is already for an appropriate limit of opposite charges.  If the same limit is taken for like charges, then one simply gets the potential for a point charge.  I encourage you to explicitly work all of this out yourself, and then you'll be equipped to answer these questions for yourself!

Comment: Thanks for the guides, I didn't mean that. I will post a question will @ping you there. :)